# Ruby instance reference in class method?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to fill in class variables for a class instance from a file, and the only way I've managed to figure how to do this is something like

```rb
a=Thing.new
File.read("filename.ext").each_line do |arguments| #this will => things like @variable=str\n
eval( "a.instance_eval {" + arguments.chop + "}")   #hence the awkward eval eval chop
end
```

The only problem I've found is that in trying to impliment this in a class method (to do this for several instances in a go), I don't know how to make this happen:

```rb
class Thing
attr_accessor :variable

 def self.method
  File.read("filename.ext").each_line do |arguments|
   eval("instance.instance_eval{" + arguments.chop + "}")   #this line
  end
 end
end
```

namely, the reference to the instance calling the method. self will just just be Thing in this case, so is there any way to do this? More pertinent might be a better way to go about this overall. I only just learned ruby last night, so I haven't had an opportunity to see some of the neater tricks that are to be had, and my language maturity is a little fresh yet as a result.

For context, Thing is a character in a game, loading its base values from a savefile.

Comment: A better way to go about this would be, IMO, to use YAML and marshall it to and from a file. Here is a good blog post about it http://www.skorks.com/2010/04/serializing-and-deserializing-objects-with-ruby/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first off, take a look at [Marshal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Marshal.html). It's specifically used for dumping data structures to serialized formats and loading them back.

The said, if you want to persist in your direction, then try something like this:

```
class Thing
  attr_accessor :variable

  def self.method
    File.read("filename.ext").each_line do |arguments|
      ivar, val = arguments.strip.split("=", 2)
      instance.instance_variable_set(ivar, val)
    end
  end
end
```

[#instance_variable_set](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/Object/instance_variable_set) allows you to...well, set instance variables on an object by name. No ugly eval necessary!

By way of demonstration:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.instance_variable_set("@bar", "whatzits")
puts foo.bar # => whatzits
```

Comment: I like it. Honestly I'm probably going to end up using Marshal and YAML to do this at this point, but for the sake of curiosity though:  
instance.instance_variable_set(ivar, val)  
will this substitute the class instance into the method? As in, will, a=Thing.new\n a.method process a.instance_variable_set(ivar, val) or instance.instance_variable_...

Comment: It'd run `a.instance_variable_set`.

Comment: Ok, something about it bugged be, so I went to test it out in irb.  
These came up everywhere  
NameError: undefined local variable or method `instance' for #<Thing:0x7f7ca3df7c68>  
But it gave me some insight, instead of using a class method a la self.method, I was mismatching my scope, so by making an instance method of it instead, self is instance instead of class like I was thinking, and I can even use self to pull the correctly associated file if I chose to go this way ^^. Maybe I was using a different version, moot though, the insight was valuable